# Cors-policy block my request using axios get/post with query or params

Tags: node.js, express, axios, cors

this is my configuration in cors:

```
var corsOptions = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000", // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
}

app.use(cors(corsOption)
```

above is part of my code in backend
this is my request from frontend

```
const data = [{id: 1, name: "number 1"}, {id: 2, name: "number 2"}]

axios.post('http://localhost:5000/data', data)
```

when i `'POST'` the data into backend that url is works fine with my browser or postman

but when i using `req.params` or `req.query` like this:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/data/delete?id=1')
```

or like this:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/data/delete/1')
```

using postman that request works fine, but not in my browser chrome or mozilla. this also happen with method `'GET'`. and the error said that `cors` blocked my request. my backend run in port 5000 and frontend run in port 3000

complete error said:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at *my-url*. (Reason: CORS request did not
> succeed)

Comment: "the error said that cors blocked my request" — There are **lots** of reasons why your request might be blocked due to (a lack of) CORS. Please read [ask]. Quote the **full error message**.

Comment: ok. i've fixed my question

Comment: "Reason: CORS request did not succeed" is sadly, not a very helpful error message. Are there any other errors? Does using a different browser (with a different engine, such as Firefox vs Chrome) give a better error? Does the Network tab show any useful information (such as a preflight request getting an HTTP error status or the response missing the headers you've tried to add)?

Comment: sadly sir, there is no others error show in my log browser. but first of, i want to ask. is there any different between this request? and what is different? 1. axios.post('http://localhost:5000/data', data), 2. axios.post('http://localhost:5000/data/delete?id=1'), because the first one is works fine but not the number 2 @Quentin

Comment: Looking at the responses in the Network tab, as I previously suggested, should highlight any significant differences.

Comment: oke i see. this is in my browser mozilla https://ibb.co/tCwZpz0, and this is in my chrome https://ibb.co/PhWbDxW

Comment: It shows the preflight OPTIONS request failing so it isn't sending the POST request. Look at why the preflight is failing!

Comment: I matters *when* your CORS-handling middleware is executed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921629/graphql-gateway-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check/68955372#68955372

Answer (score -2):

The error message **CORS request did not succeed** suggests that the **OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/data/delete?id=1** HTTP request failed. See [related MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed).

**From MDN:**

> The HTTP request which makes use of CORS failed because the HTTP connection failed at either the network or protocol level. The error is **not directly related to CORS**, but is a fundamental **network error of some kind**.

It means that your server listening to localhost:5000 is unable to respond to the request. You should be able to solve your error by debugging your server response to the request highlighted above.